# Oracle Apex - Dynamic Header in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I need dynamic header in interactive grid, which should look like this:

01/2023, 02/2023, 03/2023, 04/2024, 05/2023, 06/2023 ... 01/2028

Display each month and year over five years. When the month is over (ex. 02/2023) it should be deleted from header and new month should be added at the end of header (ex. 03/2028).

I tried answer from following question, but it is not working.

[Show dynamic days with Month Dates in a Oracle Apex Grid Heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70605531/show-dynamic-days-with-month-dates-in-a-oracle-apex-grid-heading)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a hidden columns to supply the values dynamically through a query and then use that hidden column in group columns.